# Checking auth token valid before route enter in Vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

I have a simple use case, where my application is using `vue-router` and `vuex`. Then `store` contains a `user` object which is `null` in the beginning. After the user is validated from the server it sends back an `user` object which contains a `JWT` auth token which is assigned to the `user` object in the store. Now lets assume that the user came back after 3 hours and tried to visit a route or perform any other action, considering that the auth token has expired by then, what would be the best way to check that(need to call `axios post` to check it) and redirect user to the `login` page. My app will have loads of components so I know I can write logic to check the token valid in the `mounted` hook of each component but that would mean repeating it all of the components. Also I don't want to use the `beforeEach` navigation guard because I cannot show any visual feedback to the user like `checking...` or `loading...`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Try Vue.JS [Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)

You can define a Global Mixin and use it via `Vue.use(myMixin)` - then all Components will inherit this mixin. If you define a `mounted` or probably better `activated` hook on the mixin, it will be called on every component.

There you can use everything a component can do - `this` will point to your component. And if the component also defines a hook itself, the mixin hook of the same type will run *before* the components own hook.

### Or try a single top-level login component

We used a little different solution - we have a single component which handles everything login-related, which exists outside of the router-view in the parent index.html. This component is always active and can hide the div router-view and overlay a loading message or a login-screen. For an intranet-application this component will also use polling to keep the session alive as long as the browser stays open.

You can load of your router-navigation to this component. - So a child-component which wants to trigger a router-navigation just sets a global reactive property `navigateTo` which is watched by the top level authentication component. This will trigger an authentication check, possibly a login-workflow and after that the top-level component will call `$router.push()` With this approach you have complete control over any navigation.

Comment: Suppose if I have a `mounted` hook in the mixin, how do I make sure that the component level `mounted` is not called before some operation is complete?

Comment: I don't think there is a clean way to do this. A better way would be to define a new custom option name for this action. For example `ready` - and define your Mixin-Method to call the `ready` method of your component if it has one after your operation is complete.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pam7u01L/ An example with a mixin registering a custom "ready" function, which is called after some ajax call or something similar is done...

Answer (score 18):

I do something similar in one of my projects, it's actually deceptively difficult to handle these types of situations, but you can add a `beforeEnter` guard to your protected routes, then redirect if the authentication failed.

```
const guard = function(to, from, next) {
  // check for valid auth token
  axios.get('/api/checkAuthToken').then(response => {
      // Token is valid, so continue
      next();
  }).catch(error => {
      // There was an error so redirect
      window.location.href = "/login";
  })
};
```

Then on your route you can do:

```
{
  path: '/dashboard',
  component: Dashboard,
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
    guard(to, from, next);
  }
},
```

You may notice I've used `location.href` rather than `router.push`. I do that because my login form is csrf protected, so I need a new csrf_token.

Your other issue is going to be if the user tries to interact with your page without changing the route (i.e. they click a button and get a 401 response). For this I find it easiest to check authentication on each `axios` request and redirect to `login` when I receive a 401 response.

In terms of adding a loading spinner during the guard check you can simply add a loading flag to your vuex store then import your store into your router. Honestly though I wouldn't bother, on a decent production server the check will be done so quickly that the user is unlikely to ever see it.

Comment: I wouldn't use ` window.location.href` with vuerouter

Comment: @deathangel908 That’s specifically to refresh a Laravel CSRF token which will expire after a period of inactivity, so a router push at that point will mean the user will need to refresh that page manually to login, I find it easier to essentially force the session to refresh  for the login page. That’s just a quirk of Laravel that has to be worked around and isn’t something I would do otherwise.

Comment: the `guard` function keeps the page redirecting to itself for ever.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `interceptors` to silently get the auth token when some request happens.

```
    axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
         return response;
       }, function (error) {

              const originalRequest = error.config;

             if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {

              originalRequest._retry = true;

              const rToken = window.localStorage.getItem('rToken');
              return axios.post('url/to/get/refresh/token', { rToken })
                     .then(({data}) => {
                     window.localStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                     window.localStorage.setItem('rToken', data.refreshToken);
                     axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + data.token;
                    originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + data.token;
                    return axios(originalRequest);
           });
      }

      return Promise.reject(error);
   });
```

Comment: do you treat this as an async middleware within the router?

Comment: What about if there are no requests in your component? You will be allowed to navigate despite your token is expired

Answer (score 4):

Because you use `vuex`, you can add some state like `isLoading` or `isChecking`.

And in your `router.beforeEach`, you can check and set `isLoading` or `isChecking` follow your current checking state. Then you can show loading message follow this state.

Answer (score 2):

> In our route.js we check in beforeEnter hooks the user has token or
>   not.

route.js

```
{
   path: '/dashboard',
   name: dashboard,
   meta: {
     layout: 'home-layout'
   },
   components: {
     default: Dashboard,
     header: UserHeader
   },
   beforeEnter: ifAuthenticated,
 }
```

route.js

```
const ifAuthenticated = (to, from, next) => {
 if (localStorage.getItem(token)) {
   next();
   return;
 }
 router.push({ 
   name: 'login',
   params: {
     returnTo: to.path,
     query: to.query,
   },
 });
};
```

Comment: If the token was forcibly expired on the server-side you will be allowed to navigate since your localStorage still contains the token key

Comment: I've been trying for soooo long to find a way to grab the user's data, but couldn't use `this` in the Router to call my localStorage mixin function... didn't think of just calling `localStorage` on its own. Nice one!